# Virtual machine networking

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I can't figure it out. Can I make a network connection from a bridged VM to a NAT VM in vmware.
Basically something like this

[image]

Comment: VMware Workstation or ESX?   Can you connect from Host machine to one of the NAT machines?   In the host:  NET USE X: \\NATIP\folder and authenticate.

Comment: VMware Workstation 15.5. I can connect from Host machine. The reason is NAT VMs needs a different external IP addresses than a host machine.

Comment: Thank you. I have VMware 15.5 here with Windows 10 Host and Windows and Linux guest.  Make sure you can ping both ways (Host to Guest, Guest to Host).  Make sure there is no firewall obstruction (not usually).  If something seems not correct, you can reset the NAT networking with the VMware network editor.